# Setting up django for css file

Tags: python, css, django, webfaction

I am a newbie to django and trying to create a personal tech blog. I am hosting on webfaction.  I have setup the blog using [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srHZoj3ASmk). But the stylesheets are not working. I followed [the step-by-step procedure](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/getting-started.html#create-the-django-application) to create the static files mentioned by webfaction but still the stlyesheet is not working.

I have created a static application: `staticapp` and added it to the website with `/static`
as mentioned in the webfaction doc.

In `settings.py`:

```
  STATIC_ROOT = 'home/myaccount/webapps/staticapp'
  STATIC_URL = 'http://myblogtest.myaccount.webfactional.com/static'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 'junk','static',)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
     'blog',
     )
```

I am referencing from my html page like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style/style.css" />
```

Am I missing any step? I could see many answers saying to add a code snippet in `urls.py` but it is not mentioned in Webfaction's doc. So I haven't done that.

I could see many have faced this same problem but the answers are not helping me as I am a newbie. Kindly help me to setup this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STATIC_ROOT` needs to have a prepending slash `/`, i.e. `/home...` *not* `home...`

*DO NOT* add the `static` directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. You have my permission to smack whomever advised you to do that with the nearest blunt object. The `static` directory should *not* exist at all in development, and in production it should only ever be created or modified via `python manage.py collectstatic`.

*DO* store your static resources in either each app's individual `static` directory or an entirely different project-level directory, i.e. this directory should not be the same as that for `MEDIA_ROOT` or `STATIC_ROOT`. Then, add *this* directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

In Django 1.4+ you should use the `{% static %}` template tag in your templates:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" alt="Hi!" />
```

This will automatically append the `STATIC_URL` portion of the URL for you, so the path parameter you provide should be relative to that.

In Django 1.3, you'd use `{{ STATIC_URL }}` after ensuring that `'django.core.context_processors.static'` appears somewhere in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. Your views will also need to utilize `RequestContext`, which means using either class-based views, the `render` method, or passing `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` to `render_to_response`.

If you want Django to serve static files in development for ease, you can add the following to the end of your `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

This will *not* work in a production enviroment (`DEBUG=False`). For production, you need to run `python manage.py collectstatic` and then have your frontend webserver (nginx, Apache, etc.) serve the directory at `STATIC_URL`.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `STATIC_URL` in settings; you should use it in your html templates

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/style/style.css">
```

That should work as long as you haven't removed anything from TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.

You could also look into using an asset manager to generate all of the JS and CSS links in your templates for you, rather than writing them yourself. [django-pipeline](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) is really good, and can handle things like JS and CSS concatenation and compression for you as well.

Comment: Tried with {{ STATIC_URL }}. It did not help. Would you like to know any other information about the process that I followed?