# How can I center align(responsive) materialize forms for Django?

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms, materialize

This form is not responsive and doesn't change it's size on changing the browser size. Half of the form goes out of the card.

```
<div class="row valign">
    <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l8 offset-l2">
        <div class="card">
<form method="POST" >

        {% csrf_token %}
        {% form form=form %}{% endform %}

      <div style="text-align:center">
          <a href="#!" class="btn waves-effect waves-red z-depth-5"  onclick="Materialize.toast('Thank You!', 4000, 'rounded')">SUBMIT</a>
</div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your wanting to center both horizontally and vertically. For this I personally recommend you to use flex in your css. If you don't have a css file this is the first thing you will need to get setup. Checkout this Question here for a comprehensive answer about doing this in Django.
[Setting up django for css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712177/setting-up-django-for-css-file)

CSS

```
.card {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card form {
    max-width: 100%; /* Handles the responsive part, it will cause your form to scale with a max-width of 100% */
}
```

Checkout this guide on flexbox created by Chris at CSS Tricks. Its great and covers everything you need to know about centering.
[https://duckduckgo.com/?q=complete+guide+to+centering+css](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=complete%20guide%20to%20centering%20css)